# Django - How get IP of request in a custom receiver?

Tags: python, django

I have following code:

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):  
    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    AuditEntry.objects.create(action='User logged in', ip=ip, username=user.username)
```

It works great.

In views.py I have a custom receiver:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def user_updated(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.get('instance', None)
    ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    if user:
        new_password = user.password
        try:
            old_password = User.objects.get(pk=user.pk).password
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            old_password = None
        if new_password != old_password:
            AuditEntry.objects.create(action='Password has changed', ip="127.0.0.1", username=user.username)
```

For sure it falls with "no request found" error.

I can't figure out how to extract IP.

Thank you.

Or maybe I am overengineering my code? All I need is to create AuditEntry with parameters after User model has changed.

Comment: Did you forget the request param in the user_updated function?

Comment: user_updated() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'. It is need to passed by somehow.

Answer (score 1):

To me, It looks like you forgot the request param in your function.

You need to pass the request param.

Comment: I tried, it returned 'user_updated() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request''

Comment: then check where you call user_updated, one more thing check if Ip is in kwargs
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/